# Degrading jquery gracefullly in drupal when no javascript available. Ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, view

I would like my button in Drupal to degrade gracefully when javascript is not available by directing the user to the full node.

I've got this jquery javascript code in the head of my Drupal node-type-tpl.php;

```
  Drupal.behaviors.infobutton = function(context) {
  $("button").click(function () {
  $('.more').hide();
  $('.more').eq( $('button').index( $(this) ) ).show();
  });
  }
```

Here is the button which is in a row in a table in my node-type-tpl.php;

```
  <button>More</button>
```

This is the next row in the table which is hidden by css until I click my button ;

```
 <tr class="more"><td>some php content</td></tr>
```

Currently the user sees a trimmed down node in a view. This node opens out to reveal more content when they click on the button. I would like, to have it so the user is directed to the full node if javascript is turned off.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is to use an `<a>` tag instead of a `<button>` tag, and then call `e.preventDefault()` in your function. You could create the link like this:

```
<php print l('More', 'node/' . $node->nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => array('morelink'))); ?>
```

Note that the class format is different in Drupal 6 and 7, see 
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7

And then the javascript like this:

```
Drupal.behaviors.morelink = function(context) {
  $("a.morelink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.morelink').hide();
    $('.morelink').eq( $('a.morelink').index( $(this) ) ).show();
  });
}
```

If you want it to be an actual button control, you should use an actual form, since a `<button>` element by itself cannot redirect a browser without Javascript. Could look like

```
<form action="<?php print url('node/' . $node->nid); ?>">
  <input type="submit" class="more" value="More" />
</form>
```

You'd still need `e.preventDefault()` here. I'm not really in favor of this, though, the link method is the more common method of graceful degradation.

Finally, I'd include your Javascript using `drupal_add_js()` instead of directly in the node template, so you can take advantage of automatic caching and compression.

Comment: Woo hoo! That worked. Cept a couple of changes to the code;           `Drupal.behaviors.morelink = function(context) {
     $("a.morelink").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      $('.more').hide();
      $('.more').eq( $('a.morelink').index( $(this) ) ).show();
     });  
}`      and      `<a class="morelink" href = "<?php print url('node/' . $node->nid); ?>">More</a>`